# Trying to get cake bake tool on mac os X

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-bake

I am pulling my hair trying to figure out out to get the bake tool to work.

What i've done

Opened terminal and type in

```
cd ~
```

Then i've type in

```
vi .profile
```

Which already has the following contents

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin:/Applications/MAMP/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/cake:$PATH"
```

Now when i go into the htdocs folder and type in terminal

```
cake bake sampleapp
```

I get the following message

```
zsh: command not found: cake
```

I'm not sure on how to troubleshoot this.
Thank you for reading this :)

Comment: What do you get when you type cake in terminal? Can cake be found? Problem seems to be related to your PATH at first sight.

Comment: This is what i get: zsh: command not found: cake

Comment: Search for cake executable in file manager or from terminal using `find` command. Then fix your path with the folder you get from searching.

Comment: This is where it is and i've put in the exact value /Applications/MAMP/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/cake

Comment: I've tried to reload the .profile by typing . .profile but i get .: no such file or directory: .profile. When i do a ls -la i see the file

Comment: You don't need the CakePHP path in there. PHP suffices. You just call it relativly then (`./Console/cake`). Also note, that your path is invalid, its just `.../Console` without the trailing "cake" - which is not a path, but a file.

Comment: Hi Mark, my .profile file should be like this? export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin:$PATH" and how do i access the cake bake tool? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it :) I'm using zsh so i opened the config file like so:

```
vi .zshrc
```

Then i scrolled right to the bottom where there was paths set,

```
# Customize to your needs...
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/cake/console/folder
```

You don't have to go right to the cake console, just the folder containing it should suffice.

Now i can access the cake console.